# How can one merge or concatenate Pandas series with different lengths and empty value?

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have a number of series with blanks as some values. Something like this

```
import pandas as pd
serie_1 = pd.Series(['a','','b','c','',''])
serie_2 = pd.Series(['','d','','','e','f','g'])
```

There is no problem in filtering blanks in each series, something like `serie_1 = serie_1[serie_1 != '']`

However, when I combine them in one df, either building the df from them or either building two one-column df and concatting them, I'm not obtaining what I'm looking for.

I'm looking for a table like this:

```
    
  col1 col2

0   a   d
1   b   e
2   c   f
3   nan g
```

But I am obtaining something like this

```
0   a   nan
1   nan d
2   b   nan
3   c   nan
4   nan e
5   nan f
6   nan g
```

How could I obtain the table I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach, if I understand correctly:

```
pd.concat([
    serie_1[lambda x: x != ''].reset_index(drop=True).rename('col1'),
    serie_2[lambda x: x != ''].reset_index(drop=True).rename('col2')
], axis=1)

   col1  col2
0   a    d
1   b    e
2   c    f
3   NaN  g
```

The logic is:  select non-empty entries (with the lambda expression).  Re-start index numbering from 0 (with reset index).  Set the column names (with rename).  Create a wide table (with axis=1 in the merge function).

Comment: thanks!

I guess that when you reset_index each series, index of first and second series become the same and thus the result is the intended one, right?

Comment: That's exactly right!  Pandas aligns on the index values.  Suppose you had two series, one with city populations and the other with city land areas (both indexed by city name).  This alignment lets you divide population by area to get density, and handles missing values.

Answer (score 2):

One way using `pandas.concat`:

```
ss = [serie_1, serie_2]
df = pd.concat([s[s.ne("")].reset_index(drop=True) for s in ss], 1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     0  1
0    a  d
1    b  e
2    c  f
3  NaN  g
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just filter out the blank values before creating the dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def filter_blanks(string_list):
    return [e for e in string_list if e]

serie_1 = pd.Series(filter_blanks(['a','','b','c','','']))
serie_2 = pd.Series(filter_blanks(['','d','','','e','f','g']))

pd.concat([serie_1, serie_2], axis=1)
```

Which results in:

```
    0   1
0   a   d
1   b   e
2   c   f
3   NaN g
```

Comment: Thanks!!

But now I don't understand why filtering list works when filtering series and after that concat the series don't